# How to avoid duplicates in following SQL scenario

Tags: mysql

I have a table called LIKES as follows.

[image]

As you can see it is having two columns. UserName1, UserName2. 
What this table contains is that, If one person follow other persons facebook page etc.

For example, If Jon follow bobs page then there is a entry in the table as Jon, bob, If bob follows Jon facebook page, then there is a entry called Bob, Jon.

So I want to find out all the users who are following each others profile and I want it without duplicates.

I have following query, which give results of finding users who follow each others profile. but I am not able to remove duplicates

```
SELECT L1.USERNAME1, L2.USERNAME2 
FROM LIKES L1, 
     LIKES L2 
WHERE L1.USERNAME1=L2.USERNAME2 
     AND L1.USERNAME2=L2.USERNAME1
```

Final output from the given table should be Jon Bob, or Bob , Jon, not the both.

my query gives the both results, How can I remove the duplicates in the resluts

Comment: But he/she did provide the most colorful table illustration I've seen today.

Comment: @sstan, database is mysql , I used https://sketch.io/sketchpad/ to create the image :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [don't use comma-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). That syntax has been outdated for a long time. Second, one way you can avoid duplicates in this case is to require that the first name you report in your result set occur before the first alphabetically. You can do this safely because any pair of names that will appear in your result set must appear in the source table in both orders (e.g. ("Bob", "Jon") and ("Jon", "Bob")). I am assuming here that you don't need to deal with the case of a user who follows his own page. For instance:

```
select * 
from likes L1 
where 
    L1.username1 < L1.username2 and
    exists (select 1 from likes L2 where L1.username1 = L2.username2 and L1.username2 = L2.username1);
```

Result:

```
username1 username2
Bob       Jon
```

[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc160/1) for a SQL fiddle that demonstrates this approach using your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks a little crazy, but this actually works:

```
select min(t.username1) as username1,
       max(t.username2) as username2
  from likes t
 group by least(t.username1, t.username2),
         greatest(t.username1, t.username2)
having count(distinct t.username1) = 2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6f819/8)

**EDIT** Added the `having` clause to deal with my misunderstanding of OP's question

Comment: Clever, and it avoids my assumption that the two names are distinct from one another. :)

Comment: @sstan, ur answer gives the output where one is not following others facebook page. It should only give the results A follow B and B follow A, then results should be A, B or B, A  not both. But if A follow B only but not the other way round, then it should not come in the output

Comment: @Kltis: Ah, I misunderstood the question then.  I thought you wanted all the rows without the "logical" duplicates. Still, it was an interesting exercise.

Comment: @Kltis: Edited the query slightly to fix my misunderstanding.